# Pantalla azul cuando hago npm install

Tags: npm

Tengo un problema porque para poder ejecutar el frontend de mi proyecto necesito hacer npm install para poder despues hacer npm start, pero a la mitad, mientras instala, me sale un pantallazo azul y se reinicia el ordenador y no se como solucionarlo para que me complete la instalación sin que salga el pantallazo. La version que uso de Node es la 10.15.0 y npm 6.4.1. 
Tambien he probado a eliminar el directorio node_modules y package-lock.json y despues hacer npm install, pero a veces me vuelve a salir el pantallazo azul y otras me sale un error de que no se ha encontrado un archivo que deberia encontrarse en el siguiente path .../node_modules/eslint/node_modules/esprima/bin/esparse.js

El directorio que no aparece y por eso no encuentra espase.js es eslint

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, la verdad la información que aportas es incompleta. Entiendo tu problema, pero en realidad pueden ser muchas cosas las que suceden. ¿Has intentado el deploy en otro equipo? ¿Has intentado con una versión deiferente de S.O.? ¿Con una arquitectura distinta (32 o 64 bits)?. Este tipo de errores se depuran así. Saludos

Comment: Dudo mucho que sea un problema de npm, que lo único que hace es descargar ficheros. Es posible que tengas un problema de Hardware (disco dañado, por ejemplo) o de drivers en tu máquina